# Return combined Dataset after joinWith in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

Given the below two Spark `Datasets`, `flights` and `capitals`, what would be the most efficient way to return *combined* (i.e. "joined") result without converting first to a `DataFrame` or writing out all the columns out by name in a `.select()` method? I know, for example, that I can access either tuple with (e.g. `.map(x => x._1`) or use the `*` operator with:

```
result.select("_1.*","_2.*")
```

But the latter may result in duplicate column names and I'm hoping for a cleaner solution.

Thank you for your help.

```
case class Flights(tripNumber: Int, destination: String)

case class Capitals(state: String, capital: String)

val flights = Seq(
  (55, "New York"),
  (3, "Georgia"),
  (12, "Oregon")
).toDF("tripNumber","destination").as[Flights]

val capitals = Seq(
  ("New York", "Albany"),
  ("Georgia", "Atlanta"),
  ("Oregon", "Salem")
).toDF("state","capital").as[Capitals]

val result = flights.joinWith(capitals,flights.col("destination")===capitals.col("state"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 options, but you will have to use `join` instead of `joinWith`:

1. That is the best part of the Dataset API, is to drop one of the join columns
   , thus no need to repeat projection columns in a select: `val result = flights.join(capitals,flights("destination")===capitals("state")).drop(capitals("state"))`
2. rename join column to be the same in both datasets and use a slightly different way of specifying the join: `val result = flights.join(capitals.withColumnRenamed("state", "destination"), Seq("destination"))`

Output:

```
result.show
+-----------+----------+-------+
|destination|tripNumber|capital|
+-----------+----------+-------+
|   New York|        55| Albany|
|    Georgia|         3|Atlanta|
|     Oregon|        12|  Salem|
+-----------+----------+-------+
```